# WPF - change global styles from code

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have the below style in ResourceDictionary file

```
<Color x:Key="LightCyan">LightCyan</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightCyanBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightCyan}" />

<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,3" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False">
            <!-- Change brush color at run time -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightCyanBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I need to change the TextBox background color when `IsReadOnly = False` at run time from color hex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`, for example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxEditableBackgroundBrush"
                     Color="LightCyan" />
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="0,0,0,3" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly"
                     Value="False">
                <!-- Change brush color at run time -->
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{DynamicResource TextBoxEditableBackgroundBrush}" /> <!-- note here -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then in code you just change your brush:

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
brush.Freeze();
this.Resources["TextBoxEditableBackgroundBrush"] = brush;
```